# Is it possible to bind Content in Xaml To a Grid in code

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, grid, contentpresenter

I know this is bad practice but I have created a Grid in code and would like to bind this grid to my view.

So Far I have:

**View:**

```
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CustomerTagsView}"/>
```

**Code**

```
    private Grid _customerTagsView;
    public Grid CustomerTagsView
    {
        get { return _customerTagsView; }
        set 
        { 
            _customerTagsView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("CustomerTagsView"));
        }
    }
```

But the `Get` method is never entered. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.. The method works its just in my case the binding was incorrect...

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'CustomerTagsView' property not found on 'object' '''
>   (HashCode=16802356)'. BindingExpression:Path=CustomerTagsView;
>   DataItem='' (HashCode=16802356); target element is
>   'ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type
>   'Object')

An important lesson. Always check your output window before running to StackOverflow

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="container">
        <Border>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding newThing.CustomerTagsView}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource container}"/>
```